# Granting CloudWatch access to a lambda function deployed using the Serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

## My problem

I am writing a Lambda function using the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/).

The function is invoked by an HTTP request. 
It parses the request parameters, fetches some logs from a CloudWatch group and stream according to the parameters and replies with a summary of the logs.

I would like to grant CloudWatch read access to the Lambda function using the serverless configuration file.

## Code

The function definition (`serverless.yml`) is pretty basic:

```
service: adam-test-sls
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: eu-central-1
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
```

## What have I tried

- Searching the serverless framework forums
- Google-fu
- AWS CloudFormation documentation (The serverless framework creates CloudFormation files from its YAML configuration)

## My question

*How do I grant read (and/or write) permissions that will enable this Lambda function to access Specific CloudWatch logs?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless allows you to define a default IAM role for all functions (which should have CloudWatch access by default)

> Also by default, your Lambda functions have permission to create and write to CloudWatch logs.

You can also fine tune the IAM role for all functions, or even provide fine-grained permissions for each function using the `role` attribute.

[The reference is here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/)

Comment: So I can either use an existing role or define one in the file. For the latter case, and assuming I want more than CloudWatch logs - where can I find a proper documentation regarding the mapping between `serverless.yaml` and CloudFormation?

Comment: There is no magic. The syntax of a role definition the `serverless.yaml` file is exactly the same as the CloudFormation YAML syntax for IAM (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html). No transformation is performed by the Serverless framework.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!